# How do I add animated images before each nav menu item?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, navigation

I have the working HTML and CSS for these nav menu items, but I need to find out how to add these unique images right before each menu item in WordPress. Since these are animated on hover over the menu name, I couldn't make them work as CSS background images, so I had to put them in the HTML.

Here's the HTML:

```
<aside>
    <nav id="side-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/2020-WashoeBasket-01.png" height="25" width="34">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/2020-WashoeBasket-02.png" height="25" width="34">Dine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/2020-WashoeBasket-04.png" height="25" width="34">Visit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/2020-WashoeBasket-05.png" height="25" width="34">Culture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/2020-WashoeBasket-13.png" height="25" width="34">Lodgings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/2020-WashoeBasket-06.png" height="25" width="34">Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/2020-WashoeBasket-16.png" height="25" width="34">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</aside>
```

Here is the PHP for WordPress to automatically put the page names and links into the menu items.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Nav Menu')); ?>
```

How to add in the image links into this?

Comment: Why not use css's `before` pseudo selector? You can combine it with the `hover`selector.

Comment: If the images are fixed then just hard code the menu

Comment: The reason I didn't hard code the menu is so that it can be changed through the WordPress pages section instead of the code. That way none code savvy people can also make changes in the future.

Comment: @arkascha was about to recommend the same. So use CSS3 if you can (browser support). Have a look at [Learning To Use The :before And :after Pseudo-Elements In CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/)

Comment: @arkascha & Markus, great idea! I've gone the :before Pseudo-Element route and unfortunately I can't seem to make the 'transition' and 'transform' properties work on the image. I put in the image as 'content' and not background. But it didn't work on it as background either. I've tried firefox and webkit browsers. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried again using background-image and it transitions and transforms! But the problem is that it only works when 'position' is 'absolute' and not 'relative'! Anybody know why that is?

Comment: Ok … it actually worked with image as 'content', but again only with absolute positioning. This is strange!

Comment: The problem is that I need the images to be relatively positioned.

Comment: Well I made it all work with absolute positioning, so problem solved. And transitions don't work in webkit browsers yet, but will soon hopefully. They do work in Firefox, Chrome & IE10 though. Still don't understand why relative positioning renders transitions and transforms useless!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making the images css background with a class - and in the menu editor in the wordpress admin area you have an option to add a class to each menu item. (if its not showing click on 'screen options' and check off 'css classes').

Then add a `text-indent: -9999px;` on the menu items to show only the images.

I did it on [this website](http://myjsf.org/) for the logo in the middle.

It would be:

```
menu-item {
    background: url('http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/2020-WashoeBasket-01.png') no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

menu-item:hover{
    text-indent: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going with a mix of your answer and @arkascha & Markus' answers. Your tip is great for getting unique images for each menu item by giving them each a unique class and assigning :before pseudo elements to each list item through their unique classes.